# How to switch on validation according to WSDL - spring boot and spring-ws

Tags: java, web-services, spring-boot, soap, spring-ws

in my schema I have following element:

```
<xs:element name="deletePokemonsRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="pokemonId" type="xs:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

And I have endpoint for it:

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "deletePokemonsRequest")
@ResponsePayload
public DeletePokemonsRequest deletePokemons(@RequestPayload DeletePokemonsRequest deletePokemons){
    pokemonDAO.deletePokemons(deletePokemons.getPokemonId());
    return deletePokemons;
}
```

When I send on this endpoint:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:pok="www">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <pok:deletePokemonsRequest>               
      </pok:deletePokemonsRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

It is accepted, but it should be rejected on validation stage. Why ? Because I set `minOccurs=1`, but it accepted envelope with `0` elements.
How to turn on validation according to WSDL ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Configure a validating interceptor.

xml config

```
<bean id="validatingInterceptor" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadValidatingInterceptor">
    <property name="xsdSchema" ref="schema" />
    <property name="validateRequest" value="true" />
    <property name="validateResponse" value="true" />
</bean>
<bean id="schema" class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema">
    <property name="xsd" value="your.xsd" />
</bean>
```

or with java config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWs
public class MyWsConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors) {
        PayloadValidatingInterceptor validatingInterceptor = new PayloadValidatingInterceptor();
        validatingInterceptor.setValidateRequest(true);
        validatingInterceptor.setValidateResponse(true);
        validatingInterceptor.setXsdSchema(yourSchema());
        interceptors.add(validatingInterceptor);
    }

    @Bean
    public XsdSchema yourSchema(){
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("your.xsd"));
    }
    // snip other stuff
}
```

Comment: @HaskellFun PayloadValidatingInterceptor has also setXsdSchemaCollection() method for list of schemas

Comment: I have a problem with many files. Could you attach example with many xsd files ?

Comment: you used @Override
What you overrdided ?

Comment: The config class extends [WsConfigurerAdapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/current/api/org/springframework/ws/config/annotation/WsConfigurerAdapter.html).